# Placing page numbers on top of full screen figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, pdf, pdfpages

I have a lot of full-page images in my document, right to the edges. Some of them are jpegs, some are pdfs. I need to superimpose page numbers on top of these figures, but generally the figure obscures the number.

I have an inelegant solution for the jpegs. I use tikz to place a number like so:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{example-image-a}};
\node[inner sep=2cm, above] at (current page.south) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
```

It's not a great solution, and I am up for something better. Also, this doesn't help me with the PDFs I need to include.

Anybody got any ideas? I used to use latex a lot 20 years ago, but a little rusty . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the page number by hand, use `fancyhdr` and put the page number inside a white color box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\colorbox{white}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myfancy}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are really desperate, try putting the page number inside a node instead of `\colorbox`.

```
 \cfoot{\tikz{\node[circle,fill=white]{\thepage}}}
```

Now you have all the features of `tikz` like `opacity` etc that can be applied to the page number.

---

On ther other hand, if you are inserting full page pdfs, it is better to use `pdfpages` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\tikz{\node[circle,fill=white]{\thepage}}}%\colorbox{white}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
 %\pagestyle{myfancy}
\includepdf[pages=1-10,pagecommand={\pagestyle{myfancy}},fitpaper]{pgfmanual.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Put the `pagestyle` command using `pagecommand` macro provided by `pdfpages` package.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using \includepdf for the PDFs; I should have been clearer in my question, though I didn't really want to push anyone any particular way. Your answer doesn't work for me, but it is weird; I tried your answer and it works fine as it is. I tried it on my document and nothing (obviously I don't use example JPEGs). I tried inserting an example image and it worked perfectly on just that image! There seems to be something about my jpegs?! Anyway, I think something more sinister is going on. Unfortunately I can't share my JPEGs.

Comment: Bah, I worked it out. I'm a fool; I had a defined function in there and had accidentally included \thispagestyle{empty} in it.

Comment: @timbo: No worries. It happens to all of us sometimes :)

Comment: OK, working on my JPEGs (my home-made command accidentally had a \thispagestyle{empty} in it), but I still can't get it to work on PDFs. I've given you an up vote, and I feel ashamed of my silliness, but putting a page number on top of a PDF would be great.

Comment: @timbo My example above uses pdf images.

Comment: The pgfmanual part? I'll try that. Mind you, there really isn't much to the includepdf command; not sure how I've gotten this one wrong. I'm using \includepdf[pages={-}]{filename.pdf}. (My files are medical records, so I can't show them).

Comment: @timbo: you may try `\includepdf[pages=1-10,pagecommand={\pagestyle{myfancy}}]{pgfmanual.pdf}` i.e., put `\pagestyle` inside `pagecommand`

Comment: NOW we are gassing the cook! PERFECT! And while this might not have been challenging for you, I feel less silly about asking my question now, as I don't think that was obvious and I certainly didn't see that nugget lying around. I'll accept your answer, but would you mind appending that to it?

Comment: Actually, discovered the trick seems to be the [pages=1-10] AS WELL as the pagecommand. That is, you can't just put in [pages=-, pagecommand={\pagestyle{myfancy}}]. I have to actually put in the start and stop page.